# React responsive UI is not rendered with tiny text on mobile devices

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, media-queries

I was trying out React Material UI's [responsive drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer). It can be tried out online on the [Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/deopk) given in the docs.

I copy-pasted the code into Visual Studio Code and fired up the server.

It renders just fine in desktop mode for browser:

[image: Preview]

However, when I turn on emulation mode in dev tools, the drawer and app bar text looks tiny.

For responsive:

[image: Preview]

For Moto G4:

[image: Preview]

Is it because the resolution mismatch between Moto G4 and my laptop screen (1920x1080)? Or am I missing something?

Can someone confirm if you are getting the same behavior when run on the local machine? Or am I copy-pasting it wrong? I have tried copy-pasting code from Visual Studio Cod back to Code Sandbox and it runs just fine in Code Sandbox for `mobile responsive` view. I am not able to test it in Code Sandbox for Moto G4.

PS: I am new to front-end development.

### Update

My project structure is as follows:

[image: Preview]

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/components/DrawerNav.js**

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at
          ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum
          quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit
          laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed
          adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies
          integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Metus vulputate
          eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo
          quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat
          vivamus at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur
          lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa sapien
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est
          ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar
          elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse
          sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat consequat
          mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis
          risus sed vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas
          purus viverra accumsan in. In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non
          tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor. Habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique
          sollicitudin nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis
          eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla
          posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**src/app.js**

```
// import "./App.css";
import DrawerNav from "./components/DrawerNav";

function App() {
  return <DrawerNav />;
}

export default App;
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Please provide some code or examples so we can analyse it and debug it.

Comment: @Alan I just added the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/deopk) at the start of the question from the docs.

Comment: Cool! I saw you solved it!

Comment: @Alan I solved it by adding `<meta name="viewport" ...>`. But the example on react doc did not had this tag and still it rendered correctly. So I felt that I was still missing something. After carefully checking react's codesandbox and mine, I realised that the issue was the difference in folder hierarchy. Moving `index.html` to the same folder as js files also fixed the rendering without `<meta>` tag. But now, I am guessing why so? I asked the [detailed new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883837/). Please see if you have any idea why this is working.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that I wasn't aware that I should add:

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
/>
```

to my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" /> -->

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Adding this made it work fine.

You can see this in action on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-lake-1mrfp?file=/public/index.html:71-179). Try removing the `<meta>` tag. Also check the effect by opening output in new Google Chrome tab by going to [this](https://1mrfp.csb.app/) link and then changing emulation in Google Chrome dev tools.

[image: Preview]

More on this tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).